# Implementing viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm writing an app that  uses swipe tabs but the tabs are not swiping(I have to click on the tab to navigate) even after implementing viewpager in my code.I need the tabs to be swipable even as I have implemented viewpager it's still not swiping

Comment: write the code that you have tried so far

Comment: How do you implement your viewpager?

Comment: You can check google's sample because tabs are deprecated. Check this project [here](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html)

Comment: figured out it was the position of the viewpager in my Xml that was the cause .thanks